# AVPlayer streaming for too long when the server is far away

Tags: ios, streaming, avplayer

I'm implementing a player for iOS using `AVPlayer`.
I'm using a link to a backend service that returns a 301 and redirects to the link to the song in 7Digital.

The latencies in Spain (where I am) are:
ping to backend: 40 ms
ping to 7Digital: 20 ms

When I play the song in Spain it takes 2 seconds to start playing.

For some reason if I play that song from Singapore it takes 8 seconds to start playing. In those 8 seconds the `AVPlayer.reasonForWaitingToPlay` is `AVPlayerWaitingWhileEvaluatingBufferingRateReason` until it starts to play.

The latencies in Singapore are:

ping to backend: 360 ms.
ping to 7Digital: 300 ms.

I tried with different players like the `VLCKit` and `StreamingKit` with the same results.

Also I tried with `[player playImmediatelyAtRate:1]` and     `player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling=false;` with same results too.

If I use this song: [http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3][1], it takes 4 seconds to start playing in Singapore and it takes 2.5s in Spain.

ping to techslides.com from Singapore: 500 ms.
ping to techslides.com from Spain: 150 ms.

If I play this songs from the browser it has no delay in both Spain and Singapore.

Any idea whats happening here? It's really confusing.

Edit:

This is the code that im using:

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling=false;
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timeControlStatus" options:0 context:nil];

    //[player play];
    [player playImmediatelyAtRate:1];
```

Comment: share the code what are you doing? How are you initializing the url and playing?

Comment: Ok, i'll edit the question

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same issue but when trying to stream from 7digital in Denmark. For some tracks it takes up to 15 seconds to start playing. Playing in the browser however is instant.

Comment: Nope sorry i start using another library